# 'Can you help' message when logged in

Tags: discussion

I just start my browser again with Opendata as its start page, click on a question without answers, and see this:

[image]
Isn't the...

> Can you help? Open Data Stack Exchange depends on everyone sharing their knowledge. If you're able to answer this question, please do!

...message a bit superfluous for a logged-in user?

Answer (score 2):

As explained on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289234/340816) this is an experiment to test the effectiveness of a new call to action.

Comment: Thanks. I hope they measure separately for logged on users and anonymous users - I have the idea the response may differ a lot between these two groups.